# Struggling with OpenLDAP configuration

Tags: amazon-ec2, ldap, openldap, access-control

I've been configurating a LDAP server on a linux instance using AWS EC2.
Up to now, I successfully set up LDAP and phpLDAPadmin to work together.

I've created Users and Groups "Organisation Units". I've added users and groups to those "OU"s.
Now I want to grand access to specific parts of my LDAP tree to the "Users" members of a "Group". That's what I wasn't able to configure up to now...

My LDAP tree looks like this:

```
+--> dc=www,dc=website,dc=com (3)
  ---> cn=admin
  +--> ou=groups (4)
  | ---> cn=admin_users
  | ---> cn=app1_users
  | ---> cn=app2_users
  | ---> cn=basic_users
  +--> ou=users (3)
  | ---> cn=user1
  | ---> cn=user2
  | ---> cn=user3
```

Let's say that I added user1 + user2 to the "memberUid" list of "app1_users" and user2 + user3 to the "memberUid" list of "app2_users".

I want:

- cn=admin have full rights/access to the tree
- app1_users can connect (to phpLDAPadmin) and add new members to the the group itself
- the same for app2_users' users

A connected user (on phpLDAPadmin) should only see the tree (and child substrees) he's part of.

Here are the ACI I tried (but whose were obsiouvly not working):

```
access to attrs=shadowLastChange
    by self write
    by dn="cn=admin,dc=www,dc=website,dc=com" write
    by * read

access to attrs=userPassword
    by self write
    by dn="cn=admin,dc=www,dc=website,dc=com" write
    by anonymous auth by * none

access to dn.base=""
    by * read

access to dn.subtree="cn=app1_users,ou=groups,dc=www,dc=website,dc=com"
    by group.base="cn=app1_users,dc=www,dc=website,dc=com" write
    by dn.base="cn=admin,dc=www,dc=website,dc=com" write 
    by * none

access to dn.subtree="cn=app2_users,ou=groups,dc=www,dc=website,dc=com"
    by group.base="cn=app2_users,dc=www,dc=website,dc=com" write
    by dn.base="cn=admin,dc=www,dc=website,dc=com" write 
    by * none

access to *
    by self write
    by dn="cn=admin,dc=www,dc=website,dc=com" write
    by * read
```

Is there something wrong with my configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say that I added user1 + user2 to the "memberUid" list of "app1_users" and user2 + user3 to the "memberUid" list of "app2_users".

This does not work with *posixGroup* entries with *memberUid* as member attribute. *memberUid* only contains a short username and not a DN.

As [slapd.access(5)](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapd.access) clearly states group ACLs only work with member attributes containing the full distinguished name (DN) of each member entry:

```
   The statement group=<group> means that access is  granted  to  requests
   whose  DN  is  listed  in the group entry whose DN is given by <group>.
   The  optional  parameters  <objectclass>  and  <attrname>  define   the
   objectClass  and  the  member  attributeType  of  the group entry.  The
   defaults are groupOfNames and member, respectively.
```

Some notes about your ACLs:

- Omit the ACL for attribute *shadowLastChange* because LDAP shadow map is a broken concept. And if you do use shadow maps, your ACL (probably copy&paste from some how-to) would allow the user to circumvent shadow password expiry.
- Do not grant implicit read privilege to *userPassword* by using the inclusive write access. Use the write-only privilege `=w` instead.

See also my answer to this question on **serverfault**:

[Set ACL in OpenLDAP so that user can find its own entry from filtered subtree](https://serverfault.com/a/922829/479197)

And before going down that route yourself I'd recommend to consider using one of the systems I mentioned in other answers:

[Centralised NSS backend for Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/51157/39586)

[How to only allow users and/or groups access certain client machines that are connected to an openldap server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/779332/how-to-only-allow-users-and-or-groups-access-certain-client-machines-that-are-co/922689#922689)